# Node.js How to always listen to Rest api?

Tags: node.js, api, socket.io

Hey I want to build my first node.js app and I would like to get some guidance.
So I have external service that provide me Rest Api with pricing list.
The pricing update every few seconds, I want to listen to this api and update my database every time I get new changes.
I come from PHP and for example here I can make Cron job and make foreach on all the table, but I know it's not smart idea, and I know node.js  made for this.
I would like to get any ideas how to start to build something like that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use an Event Emitter:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events')
var ee = new EventEmitter()
ee.on('message', function (text) {
    //Here you would update your database
    console.log(text)
})
ee.emit('message', 'hello world')//You would call this whenever/wherever the API sends your data
```

NPM events:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/events

NodeJS Docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/events.html